# git, oauth2 token and GIT_ASKPASS

Tags: git, oauth, bitbucket

I'm using Bitbucket and would like to get an automatic pull/push/clone working without using my plane password. I made some progress with generating Oauth2 access tokens for that purpose. My script looks like this:

```
consumer_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
consumer_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

oauth2_return_str=$(curl -X POST https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -u "${consumer_key}:${consumer_secret}" -d grant_type=client_credentials 2>/dev/null)
oauth2_token=$(echo $oauth2_return_str | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's|[",]||g')

echo $oauth2_token
```

There is a `clone` one liner possible:

```
git clone "https://x-token-auth:$(curl -k -X POST https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -u "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -d grant_type=client_credentials | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's|[",]||g')@bitbucket.org/USER/REPO.git"
```

Anyway instead of rewriting the `config` file every hour (the tokens are valid just one hour) I found out that `GIT_ASKPASS` seems appropriate for that purpose:

```
GIT_ASKPASS
    If this environment variable is set, then git commands which need to
    acquire passwords or passphrases (e.g. for HTTP or IMAP authentication)             
    will call this program with a suitable prompt as command line argument 
    and read the password from its STDOUT. See also the core.askpass option 
    in git-config(1).
```

For completeness:

```
core.askPass
    Some commands (e.g. svn and http interfaces) that interactively ask for
    a password can be told to use an external program given via the value of 
    this variable. Can be overridden by the GIT_ASKPASS environment 
    variable. If not set, fall back to the value of the SSH_ASKPASS 
    environment variable or, failing that, a simple password prompt. The 
    external program shall be given a suitable prompt as command-line 
    argument and write the password on its STDOUT.
```

So I wrote a test script:

```
GIT_ASKPASS=gen-token.bat
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

git clone "https://x-token-auth@bitbucket.org/USER/REPO.git"
```

BUT it is still prompting me with the password dialogue. If I then enter a generated token everything works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Ok git seems a little picky about the environment variables. I cahnged the test script to

```
GIT_ASKPASS=gen-token.bat git clone "https://x-token-auth@bitbucket.org/USER/REPO.git"
```

and it then worked. `git config --global core.askPass /path-to/gen-token.sh` makes the sript available globally.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why cannot you use SSH keys?

Comment: As I said: "I'm using Bitbucket and would like to get an automatic pull/push/clone working without using my plane password". SSH does not offer different permissions like read only. Besides that I'm on Windows and would like to avoid the hassle with it.

Comment: SSH offers read-only (on a per-repository basis, too) using "deployment keys".

Comment: OK I see you're for SSH but this is really not the way I want to go. Espiecially because it is even less compatible than my targeted solution. Thank you for the suggestion but please have another look at my post and see if you can make it working.