# git fetch origin using https and token fails

Tags: git

I can fetch the origin by navigating to the folder and:

```
git fetch origin
```

And then execute:

```
git diff origin/master --name-only
```

Which shows me the files on the server that are not the same as the local files which is what I am looking for.

But I cannot find the correct syntax to do this via https using a token, I have looked at the help page (https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/) and there seems to be nothing there that describes how to do this.

This does not error, but it does not appear fetch the same way as the command above does and executing 'git diff' does not correctly show the files.

```
git fetch https://5e99326e6f628dxxxxx@github.com/myname/repo.git :origin
```

So how can I use a token to fetch the origin ?

## EDIT

To avoid confusion, the request is succesfull and there is no problem with authentication that works, however the url that I use does NOT enable me to issue the git diff command afterwards and see a list of files that are different on the server.

If I use the first command "git fetch origin" then I am able to see the dirfferences, use the second https command and I cannot see the differences,

## So to re-summarise:

```
git fetch origin
git diff origin/master --name-only
> changed files ARE shown


git fetch https://5e99326e6f628dxxxxx@github.com/myname/repo.git :origin
git diff origin/master --name-only
> changed files are NOT shown
```

Comment: What do you mean "via https using a token"? What help page did you look at?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add it: https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/

Comment: as in my post, I want to execute git fetch origin without being prompted for username and password and use the oauth token instead.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640723/git-oauth2-token-and-git-askpass). Alternatively you can set up SSH instead.

Comment: Or maybe this is what you want: https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens/

Comment: Authentication is not a problem, that works fine, the problem is I am unable to return the origin as I do with the first command line option.

Comment: Are you using the same git diff command in both cases? If not, please show us the second version?

Comment: The second version is in the post "git fetch https://5e99326e6f628dxxxxx@github.com/myname/repo.git :origin"

Comment: "git fetch origin" works, "git fetch https://5e99326e6f628dxxxxx@github.com/myname/repo.git :origin" does not work.

Comment: I am confused... does the fetch work or not? Is your problem with git fetch or git diff?

Comment: Issuing the command "git fetch origin" works and allows me to then execute"git diff origin/master --name-only" which correctly shows me the changed files. issuing the command "git fetch https://5e99326e6f628dxxxxx@github.com/myname/repo.git :origin" does not error, but if I then issue "git diff origin/master --name-only" the changed files are NOT listed.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to execute git fetch origin without being prompted for username and p
>   password and use the oauth token instead

First, unless you are using 2FA ([Securing your account with two-factor authentication (2FA)](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/)), you don't need a token.
A [**git credential helper**](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) would be enough to cache your credentials.

Second, considering the [OAuth token section](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#via-oauth-tokens), try with username:token.
(Meaning token as a password)

Comment: Thatks, but the request is successful, there is no problem with authentication, but it does not fetch the origin as the first command line does.

Comment: @crankshaft fetching does not require authentication unless your repo is private. And if you already fetched, it would not fetch any additional commits.

Comment: It is private repo and the git diff command does not show the changed files, however using the command "git fetch origin" and the changed files are shown, so it does not appear to be pulling the same way that "git fetch origin" does.

Comment: OK. dod you try the syntax I suggest?

Comment: sorrie, but which syntax ?? -

Comment: `git fetch https://username:token/user/repo.git`: ise the token as password, not as user.

Comment: I just tried it, result is the same, no errors, but when I issue "git diff origin/master --name-only" the files that are different on the server are NOT listed. This is something related to getting ORIGIN as opposed to an an authentication issue.

Comment: Can you try without the colon (:origin): git fetch ... origin (not :origin)

Comment: Tried it earlier, just tried again: "fatal: Couldn't find remote ref origin"

Comment: @crankshaft What git remote -v returns? What OS and git version are you using?

Comment: you can test yourself: 1) clone  repo, 2) change a file on the repo server, 3) run "git fetch origin" 4) run "git diff origin/master --name-only" and the file you changed should be listed. Then do the same thing again only this time instead of "git fetch origin" use "git fetch https://5e99326e6f628dxxxxx@github.com/myname/repo.git :origin" instead.

Comment: @crankshaft  What git remote -v returns? What OS and git version are you using?

Comment: O/S is UBUNTU 16, git remote -v        
origin https://github.com/myuser/myrepo.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/myuser/myrepo.git (push)